# Make java program return value to calling shell script

Tags: java, shell, unix

Unix gurus!

I have a **Java program** which passes some parameters to a **Servlet**. The Servlet enters the info into a DB and returns back the *ID* of a row created back to the java program that calls it. The **Java program** is run in a Unix **shell script**, which later goes on to call another java program **Java Program_2** (say).

My issue is this - I need to pass the *ID* we get from **Java Program** as a parameter to **Java Program_2** in that same shell script. ARe there any best practice for this?

**Things i am working with so far -**

1) Make the java program return an exit code with `System.exit()`. 2 questions with this - **How do i catch the exit code in a variable in the shell?** Is this the right way to do it? Exit code is actually meant for returning the success parameter of the program...

2) Write the output in a file `java Java_Program >opt.txt`. If I do this, then **how do I read the contents of `opt.txt` in a shell variable again?**

Thanks a lot!

**Edit:** I should have mentioned this before actually... the programs are in different machines. I ssh into the other machine using the script..and then run java program 2. Hence, I cannot pipe the two.

Comment: Just check `$?`.  If it is 0, the program is considered to have exited without error, while if it is non-zero, it is considered to have a failure exit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would not recommend using the exit status to carry data, for the reasons you've stated.  Catching the exit status depends on what shell you're using, but in Bash, the special `$?` variable contains the exit status of the last process executed.

Writing data to stdout is far more idiomatic.  In Bash, you capture it as follows:

```
output=$(java Java_Program)
```

or:

```
output=`java Java_Program`
```

(You will often hear arguments that the first syntax is to be preferred.)

You can then feed this to stdin of your next process with:

```
echo $output > java Java_Program_2
```

More simply, you can simply pipe your processes together:

```
java Java_Program | java Java_Program_2
```

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly. However I should have added another thing...the two programs are in different machines. I ssh into the other and then run the second java program (in the same shell script). Now the issue is.. I cannot use the variable on one machine on the other.

Comment: @Jai: Fair enough.  By the way, did you just downvote this?  If you just updated your question to include a crucial detail, it doesn't really make sense to then go and downvote all the people who gave you correct answers to the original question!

Comment: No no no... I did not. I had actually upvoted you before. Even i found it weird that this answer got downvoted

Comment: @Jai: Ok then.  Someone downvoted at the same time as you left your comment.  Oh well!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if I missed something but it sounds to me that you could just let the first program write to stdout and pipe both programs together, couldn't you? You wouldn't even need a shellscript.

Comment: I should have mentioned this before actually... the programs are in different machines. I ssh into the other machine using the script..and then run java program 2

Comment: @Jai no problem - just use `ssh other-machine-name java Program1 | java Program2`

Comment: @Robin Green - Works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In your Java Program print out the id using `System.out.println(id);`

In your shell script you can execute the Java Program and store the id in a variable. For example:

```
ID=$(java JavaProgram)
```

Now, execute Java Program_2 with the id:

```
java JavaProgram2 $ID
```

In Java Program_2, the ID will come into your `main` method in `args[0]`.

You can even do this in a single step:

```
java JavaProgram2 $(java JavaProgram)
```

By the way, if you have output in a file called `opt.txt` you can read its contents into a variable like this:

```
CONTENTS=$(cat opt.txt)
```

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly. However I should have added another thing...the two programs are in different machines. I ssh into the other and then run the second java program (in the same shell script). Now the issue is.. I cannot use the variable on one machine on the other. I will still go with this as the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with option 1 as the range of exit codes you can use is very limited, some of them have special meanings, and it's not portable.

For option 2, simply use `variable="$(command)"` or

```
variable="`command`"
```

(I used double quotes in case there are any spaces in the output of `command`, but I guess that's dumb because your parameter must be a single number!)

In your case you could either use `cat opt.txt` as the command, or you could cut out the middleman and directly call the first Java program in your command (then you wouldn't need an `opt.txt` file at all). You can even cut out the variable and do it all in one line.

Comment: `export` is generally unnecessary, unless you intend `variable` to become an environment variable visible to child processes.

Comment: The quotes are senseless in the assignment; the parenthesis or the deprecated backticks capture the whole output. `var=$(echo "foo  bar")`* is sufficient - just for the output it makes a difference, whether you use `echo $var` or `echo "$var"`, but you don't save them later, if you use them in the assignment. *)There are two spaces between foo and bar.

Answer (score 0):

So you capture the output of the ssh-command:

```
java Prg2 $(ssh host java Prg1))
```

Using the exit code is not a good idea, because exit-codes, different from 0, normally indicate error.