# How to call a parametrized function using ADB and return the output back to ADB command prompt?

Tags: java, android-studio, service, adb, command-prompt

I am trying to create an application in AndroidStudio that calls a service/activity/function using ADB commands, and I want to return string output back to the command line.

For example If I want to call a function that changes the timezone on my android device.

```
public static String setTimeZone(String timezone){
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setTimeZone(timezone);
   
    return //output to adb command prompt saying success
}
```

Right now I'm just calling an activity that calls this function using:

```
adb shell am start -n com.package.demo_app/.ChangeTimeZoneActivity
```

but I have to hard code the timezone string parameter (ex: hardcoding "US/Eastern"). I'd like to be able to send data to the function/activity instead, via ADB, so that way I can automate the process if I want to change the timezone to 'US/Eastern' OR 'US/Pacific' OR etc.

Furthermore, once this is achieved I'd like to send data back to the command prompt telling the user the function was successful.

The above code is just an example to explain what I'm trying to achieve, I need to know how to do this for various other cases aside from just changing timezones

How would I go about sending parametrized data to a function via ADB, AND how would I return the output back to the command prompt? I cant seem to find the answers I'm looking for. Is it even possible to just call a singular function within my app via ADB, or would I have to create an Activity first to act as the middle man? I'm still new to using ADB.

Comment: Don't know the specifics of the Android shell, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6072812/make-java-program-return-value-to-calling-shell-script) might help